# Observer and event not working

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I am new to Magento 2 and trying to do a simple observer and event function for frontend (global to all module)

My understanding is that `controller_action_predispatch` will be run before anything else.

**Expectation:**
When I run any frontend site, eg: http://www.magentosite.com/xxx, an alert box will be displayed before any other action. when the user clicks ok on the alert box, only the page will be displayed.

But I can't see an alert box there.
Hope someone can hint me which part did I implement wrongly or did I missing execute any command?

**Update:**
Do I need to register my module (eg: add registration.php file)??? because I only actually have events.xml file and TestObserver.php inside the module name only currently?

app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="test" instance="Vendorname\Modulename\Observer\TestObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/Observer/TestObserver.php

```
<?php
    namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Observer\TestObserver;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

    class TestObserver implements ObserverInterface
    {
        public function execute(Observer $observer)
        {
            echo "<script>javascript: alert('test msgbox')></script>";
        }
    }
?>
```

then run

```
php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Observer\TestObserver it  into namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Observer;

Comment: Yes, you need to register your module. Module must have __registration.php__ and __module.xml__ Or if you have only one or two files you can do with other custom modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is your final module:**

> app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendorname_Modulename',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendorname_Modulename" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="test" instance="Vendorname\Modulename\Observer\TestObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/Observer/productSaveAfter.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class TestObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        echo "<script>javascript: alert('test msgbox')></script>";
        echo "Testing"; exit;
    }
}
```

Now run this commands

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

Remove **/var** for magento 2 and remove **/var** and **/generated** for Magento 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Your namespace is wrong. It should look like:

```
<?php

namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class TestObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        echo "<script>javascript: alert('test msgbox')></script>";
    }
}
```

Also, don't close out your class with a closing php tag `?>`

I am not sure your js is going to fire as it going to be echo'd out to the page before anything else. If you must echo something to the page, just do something you will see, such as `echo 'Hola!'; die;`

To answer the remaining question, you need to create an actual module and this would consist of a minimum of the following files:

```
Vendorname/Modulename/composer.json
Vendorname/Modulename/registration.php
Vendorname/Modulename/etc/module.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your observer with following:

### app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/Observer/TestObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class TestObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        echo 'any message'; 
        echo "<script>javascript: alert('test msgbox')></script>";
        die();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In magento2's, a module  should have below files:

- `registration.php`
- `etc/module.xml`
- `composer.json`

But other seems ok in my end

Answer (score 0):

Your Observer looks fine but I think your module is incomplete or it has typos

Use Mage2Gen to generator your basic module and apply your observer execute method

See the following example module

> https://mage2gen.com/load/347970d6-a607-4773-b65a-467d6528bfce

Apply this method

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    echo "<script>javascript: alert('test msgbox')></script>";
    echo "Testing"; exit;
}
```